# Predicting next bit in a non random sequence

Tags: random, cryptography, bit, random-testing

I have a nonrandom sequence of bits - I'm able to tell that the sequence is nonrandom because I have performed on it the runs test, moreover the sequence presents autocorrelation at lag 1 equal to 0.4 (right before the cutoff) whereas the partial auto correlation function has a sinusoidal behaviour... any suggestion on how to exploit those regularities, without assuming that the sequence follows a binomial distribution?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you would ask this on the math.SE or crypto.SE sites, not on StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on math or crypto.

Comment: It is more suited for https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ or https://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Even in cryptography people found the question off-topic... But I seriously think that there can be a deterministic answer, maybe trying to decode the sequence piece by piece using polynomials... I'm still not getting an answer in math.stackexchange, so the question is not trivial at all